# ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting) Requirements check failed for JDK 8

Tags: java, android

l am using IONIC and Cordova to build android app. When i run this command : `sudo ionic cordova build android` l have following issue :

```
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 14.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

ionic info :

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.2.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.9
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.1
   native-run  : 1.0.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.18.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.5
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.5 Build version 11E608c
```

Ionic Requirements

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 14.0.1
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-30,android-29,android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,android-23,android-22,android-21,android-20,android-19,Google Inc.:Google APIs:19
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle 
in your path, or install Android Studio

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple macOS: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 11.5
ios-deploy: installed 1.10.0
CocoaPods: not installed 
CocoaPods was not found. Please install version 1.0.1 or greater from https://cocoapods.org/
Some of requirements check failed
```

.bash_profile :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/dylan/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/dylan/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/dylan/.android/avd
export PATH=${PATH}:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
export GRADLE_HOME=~/Development/gradle-6.5.1/bin
```

Java version :

```
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+14, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Matching Java Virtual Machines :

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    1.8.0_251, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home
```

l followed and applied  all answers on stackoverflow withe same my issues , but i still have same problem when i want build android app .

any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i have solved . I edited the `~/.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8.0_251`
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/dylan/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/dylan/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/dylan/.android/avd
export PATH=${PATH}:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=~/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=~/.android/avd
export GRADLE_HOME=~/Development/gradle-6.5.1/bin
// Carefully add $GRADLE_HOME folder root . 
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$GRADLE_HOME"
```

is very important to add `$GRADLE_HOME` root folder to avoid this problem

Then

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

First your `.bash_profile` exports most of vars twice which is wrong. But the the main thing is that for an interactive shell, the `~/.bash_profile` file is not executed. Luckily the `~/.bashrc` is so export from there instead.

Comment: Thnak you for answring . l am new on Mac os Catalina .  When i write `~/.bashrc` i have `zsh: permission denied: /Users/macbook/.bashrc`

Comment: what i have to do ?

Comment: when i edit  .bash_profile i do following step .  `open -a TextEdit ~/.bash_profile` then `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Bashrc is not an executable. If you want to reload it you need to `source` it like this: `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: i have same issue

Comment: which means what exactly?